# Android addition of numerical values

Tags: android

just trying to get two sum of to numbers,
first number in edittext1
second number in edittext2
when the button is clicked
the answer goes to textview1
here is the code but after clicking the buttom the app crashes

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;
    EditText et1 ,et2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);

        }
    public void add (View v) {
        Integer x1= Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
        Integer x2= Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
        Integer x=x1+x2;
        tv1.setText(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the result to string:

```
tv1.setText(x.toString());
```

If you pass an int Android will assume it's a resource id and try to look up a string resource.